# Latest kernel installed, but not running

Tags: 10.04, server, kernel, upgrade

I have a server, the current running kernel is `2.6.32-26-server`, but I also have the following versions installed (installed through doing aptitude full-upgrade, but not rebooted):

```
linux-image-2.6.32-25-server
linux-image-2.6.32-26-server
linux-image-2.6.32-27-server
linux-image-2.6.32-30-server
```

I'd ideally like the server to running on 2.6.32-30-server, but I'm not sure how to get it to boot into that version. The menu.lst file has this entry as the first.

```
title      Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS, kernel 2.6.32-30-server
uuid       e1a13f41-eb75-4ebe-aa30-a1699ea7523b
kernel     /vmlinuz-2.6.32-30-server root=UUID=4d012511-0277-4747-8eda-e3734fbb91d4 ro quiet splash 
initrd     /initrd.img-2.6.32-30-server
```

How can I set the kernel to boot from?

Thanks

Comment: try removing the two kernels update 25 and 26. Also try updating the grub as well

Comment: You could also see what grub lists pressing `shift` during initiation of boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable GRUB_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub defines the entry to boot by default (counting from 0). The default value is zero, which means that the first entry is going to boot.

Comment: just note, that auto configurations have "mind on their own" as result that default can change. As result, when new kernel is installed GRUB_DEFAULT can change to value larger than 0 to boot previous kernel that is known to boot. That happened to me on several Ubuntu server installations, never on desktop.